# Suspend sync globally in ArgoCD?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

Is there a way in Argo CD to suspend sync globally? For example, my company occasionally does deployment freezes in which no one is allowed to ship to production. Is there a way to turn off sync globally in Argo CD to prevent new versions of apps from deploying?

Comment: scale the `argocd-application-controller` to 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As LostJon commented, you can scale the application controller down. But then you won't see the current state of resources in the UI - only the state as of the moment the controller was shut down.

Instead of scaling down the controller, you can set a [sync window](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/sync_windows/) on a [global project](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/projects/#configuring-global-projects-v18).

Comment: That sounds perfect for us, thank you for the reply!